# Xamarin Forms - Modal "Wizard" UX

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, user-experience

- Xamarin Forms
- iOS
- Android
- FreshMVVM

We have a standard non modal flow in our app that captures data from Bluetooth devices. However if the user tries to capture data of a type where we have no configured Device we jump out to a Modal page and ask them to set one up.

That modal flow could be from 2 to 5 pages long depending on the device.

1. Is Modal the right choice? It is an unfriendly stack to deal with
2. Once you take the user into a modal flow of more than one page should each page be a new Modal page
   pushed onto the Modal stack? I am wondering if once in the Modal page i do "page-like" transitions within a single ContentPage

Answer (score 0):

> Is Modal the right choice? It is an unfriendly stack to deal with

That depneds on the needs of scene . To my knowledge ,  Modal page could be a good choice . If not need to navigate to too many pages later , Modal page will be the suggested choice .

> Once you take the user into a modal flow of more than one page should each page be a new Modal page pushed onto the Modal stack? I am wondering if once in the Modal page i do "page-like" transitions within a single ContentPage

If there are more than one pages need to navigate ,the new Modal page will be pushed onto the Modal stack .

**Therefore** , if there are too much needs to use more than one page , not doing that . I'm not knowing of the scene in your project .From shared logic , the Modal page need to configure the info of bluetooth device . I will use some paging controls inside one Modal page to do , such as [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) , [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/), and [CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/) etc.

Even though using Normal page, also will recommand to use paging controls to solve the scene which needs much pages. This will make your app has a better user experience .